# jQuery: как заблокировать "двойной" скроллинг между двумя блоками

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два div-блока **#block1** и **#block2**. При скроллинге первого блока путем перемещения его скроллбара должен скроллится второй блок, т.е.

```
$('#block1').scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#block2').scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

В то же время при скроллинге второго блока, но на этот раз крутя над ним роликом мыши (mousewheel), а не путем перемещения его скроллбара, должен скроллится первый блок. Если дописываю вторую функцию

```
<script src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
...
$('#block2').mousewheel(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('#block1').scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
```

то при скроллинге второго блока мышей запускается кроме второй также первая функция и скроллинг получается неправильным, как будто "двойной" скроллинг, один в другом.

Как в первой функции вместо `scroll(function()` указать конкретно "перемещение скроллбара", чтобы не было вышеописанной проблемы?

Comment: Как вариант проверять в первой функции что ты производишь скролл не мышью. Насколько мне известно , надо с объектом event что-то мутить. Но конкретно не подскажу (мб надо смотреть на флаги какие - нужно искать). К тому же (я могу ошибаться) но вызывая у второй функции метод scrollTop, ты также активируешь срабатывание метода scroll(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть вот такой вариант:

Первый скролится только, если перемещать scrollbar.
Второй, если крутить мышкой.

```js
$('#block1').on("scroll", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('#block2').scrollTop(scrollTop);
});

$('#block2').mousewheel(function(e, i) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() - i * 10;
  $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop);
  $('#block1').scrollTop(scrollTop);
});
$('#block1').mousewheel(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#block1,
#block2 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
}
#block1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.inside {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">
  <div class="inside">jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML.[3] jQuery is the most popular JavaScript library in use today, with installation on 65% of the top 10 million highest-trafficked sites on the Web.[4][5][6]
    jQuery is free, open-source software licensed under the MIT License.[2] jQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and develop Ajax applications. jQuery also provides
    capabilities for developers to create plug-ins on top of the JavaScript library. This enables developers to create abstractions for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, themeable widgets. The modular approach to the
    jQuery library allows the creation of powerful dynamic web pages and Web applications.</div>
</div>
<div id="block2">
  <div class="inside">jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML.[3] jQuery is the most popular JavaScript library in use today, with installation on 65% of the top 10 million highest-trafficked sites on the Web.[4][5][6]
    jQuery is free, open-source software licensed under the MIT License.[2] jQuery's syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select DOM elements, create animations, handle events, and develop Ajax applications. jQuery also provides
    capabilities for developers to create plug-ins on top of the JavaScript library. This enables developers to create abstractions for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, themeable widgets. The modular approach to the
    jQuery library allows the creation of powerful dynamic web pages and Web applications.</div>
</div>
```